# Mysql match against unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, match, against

I have a problem with this mysql query:

```
select * from tb1 as a 
 where (select count(*) from tb2 as b 
         where Match(b.column1) against(`a.id`) )  = '1'
```

Mysql has this error:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause'

So I want to get all entries in tb1 where the number of entries in tb2 where a.id is inside the 'column1' column is 1.

I hope you understand my purpose otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: what do you mean by "a.id is inside the 'column1' column, could you give us an example? At least the data type of these two columns.

Comment: Sure:
id is an INT and column1 is a text like [1000,2000,3000,4000].

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: @eggyal it is not helping me now, but can you tell me how to make it better next time?

Comment: Is the best way really to have something like id,typeid,value? so to have a new row for each entry? I was thinking that my solution is better, but now I think it's not :D

Comment: @Wikunia: Yes, that's exactly the right solution.

Comment: To clarify error `select * from tb1 as a` produces the same result  as `select * from tb1` ie no column `a.id`.It should be `select id from tb1`

Comment: @davidstrachan it doesn't matter if it is select * from tb1 as a or select id from tb1 as a

Answer (score 0):

The table name should be outside the quotes, "a.id" is now handled as the column name (which off course doesn't exists), instead of a table.column pair:

```
against(a.`id`)
```

Comment: Then this error exists: #1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST

Comment: You're doing a full text search on a non string column (and it's not necessary to do a FULL TEXT search here) that's the problem i think.

This should do it: 

SELECT * FROM tb1 AS a 
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb2 as b 
         WHERE b.column1 = a.id) = 1

Comment: ah no this is actually not the same the count(*) = 1 means that there is only one row matching.

Comment: I thought you meant it that way. What result do you expect then?

Comment: there is an row where column1 is [1000,2000,3000,4000] and one with [1000,1001,2000,3000,4000] and I want to have the id 1001 because it is only in one row but this id (1001) is not the only one in this row

Comment: Then the count should be 0 right? Try this one then:

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table1.column1 = table2.id);

Comment: the column is never = id.

Comment: Then you can just change it to the column you want (i got 'id' from your OP)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37259/discussion-between-wikunia-and-davey)

Answer (score 0):

I'm nearly sure that the problem is in data range. You use a subquery and in this subquery there is no info about 'a'. You can use data from subquery in main query but not inversely. Try something like that (I can't test it so I can't guarantee query works):

```
SELECT a.*, b.count(*) FROM tb1 AS a 
LEFT JOIN tb2 AS b ON Match(b.column1) against(a.id)
HAVING b.count(*) = 1
```

Comment: He has problems with b.count(*) and with a.id in against again. :(

Comment: AGAINST needs a string not an integer. From MySQL docs:
"AGAINST takes a string to search for". So this won't work anyway.

Comment: Well I've never used `MATCH...AGAINST` before and assumed that this part is ok. But it isn't! Documentation says: **The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row**. So you need to find another approach for this condition.